# Is it possible to have a taxonomy archive that lists taxonomy terms?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

For example, I have a post type called foo. I can view all posts of type foo at the following url: mysite.com/foo.

I then attach a taxonomy called bar, in which the terms are foobar and foobaz.

I can access the posts assigned the term foobar at mysite.com/bar/foobar. But is it possible to get an archive containing foobar and foobaz at the url mysite.com/bar?

Yes, I am aware that I can just create a page and call wp_list_categories(), but I was looking for an automatic solution that mirrors the post type functionality.

Comment: So you'd like `mysite.com/bar` to list all *posts* that have at least one term in the `bar` taxonomy?

Comment: No. I want mysite.com/bar to have links to mysite.com/bar/foobar and mysite.com/bar/foobaz

A listing of the _terms_

Comment: Then the solution you mentioned (page template) would probably be the best. You could automate the process for multiple taxonomies with rewrite rules, but it seems a little superfluous for just one!

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

What TheDeadMedic said in the comments. A page would do the trick with a custom template. If you're not wanting to mix these landing pages with actual pages - the [wp-taxonomy-landing](https://github.com/crowdfavorite/wp-taxonomy-landing) plugin/library should do the trick.